# fetch 1 message at given offset when debugging app using spring-kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I understand, that random access in inefficient. But app failed, record content is (let's assume it) big for logging or otherwise inappropriate (that's true without assumption), so I only have info, that record at this offset failed and why. Good, now I want to see the data, let's say to be able to reproduce it. How to do that?

OK, I can use ConsumerSeekAware consumer, but that will rewind the position and process *all* records from that position on. I don't want that, I want just 1 specific message. I can use specific consumer in specific consumer group for this use case not to influence others and set ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG to 1 so that each pull returns just 1 record, but this will not stop all records from reaching the listener. Since there is no way how to call poll manually, programmatically. Right? Or is there such a way? Or other how to achieve this? Even if I try to reach spring-kafka internals, the org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.The consumer seems to be made inaccessible on purpose, or at least I do not see the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just create your own consumer manually and poll it.

Get a reference to the consumer factory and call `createConsumer("tempGroup", "tempClient").

You would need to create a second consumer factory with `max.poll.records=1`.

You can copy the other properties from the main factory by calling `getConfigurationProperties()` -  and creating a new map from it and create a new `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory`.

Close the consumer when you are done.

Comment: @Gary Russell - Is there a reason why the client has to call consumer.close explicitly when using DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory whereas spring closes itself in the  DefaultKafkaProducerFactory ( destroy method ) ? because of different group id right ?

Comment: You **must not** ask new questions in comments to old answers - it doesn't help people find questions and answers. Consumers and Producers are very different. Producers are thread-safe and Kafka recommends you use a single producer in your app (unless you are using transactions). `close()` on Spring producer does nothing if you are not using transactions and returns the producer to a cache for re-use when you **are** using transactions. Closing a consumer tells  Kafka the consumer no longer wants records and it can allocate the partitions to another consumer (with the same group).

Comment: Point noted. Thank you Gary.